# Activity lifecycle. android:clearTaskOnLaunch

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have three activities:

1. LoginActivity
2. OptionsActivity
3. OkActivity

App lifecycle is `1` > `2` > `3`.

Say user is in `3` and press home button, then the app is closed. Then, the user reopen the app and `1` is opened. However, if back button is pressed, `3` is shown. I want to close the app when home button is pressed. Or clear activities stack when `1` is opened.

I have tried to put `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` in `LoginActivity` but it doesn't work (same behavior).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the method OnBackPressed in the activity 1 (LoginActivity) like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   moveTaskToBack(true);
   this.finish();
}
```

This should exit the app correctly when button "Back" is pressed on the LoginActivity.